# Safe way to read directory in Python

Tags: python, directory, system-calls

```
try:
    directoryListing = os.listdir(inputDirectory)
    #other code goes here, it iterates through the list of files in the directory

except WindowsError as winErr:
    print("Directory error: " + str((winErr)))
```

This works fine, and I have tested that it doesnt choke and die when the directory doesn't exist, but I was reading in a Python book that I should be using "with" when opening files. Is there a preferred way to do what I am doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are perfectly fine. The `os.listdir` function does not open files, so ultimately you are alright. You would use the `with` statement when reading a text file or similar.

an example of a with statement:

```
with open('yourtextfile.txt') as file: #this is like file=open('yourtextfile.txt')
    lines=file.readlines()                   #read all the lines in the file
                                       #when the code executed in the with statement is done, the file is automatically closed, which is why most people use this (no need for .close()).
```

Comment: Ok! Thanks. I am new to python, and am trying to learn the right way to do things, instead of "making it work"

Comment: no problem, i will add an example of a with statement just for reference.

Comment: If you're in the mood to provide more knowledge, what does "with" do. Does it just try a bunch of things that can go wrong when opening/reading from a file and kind of bundle it into an error? Corruption, not there, etc

Comment: @RonaldDregan -- It basically makes sure the file is flushed and closed when you exit the block.  That way you're not accidentally keeping around references which take up filesystem resources.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is fine. With is indeed the preferred way for opening files, but listdir is perfectly acceptable for just reading the directory.

Comment: No problem. I hope you are enjoying your adventure with Python

Comment: Yes, I am liking it very much so far. I have have done mostly C++ and Java thus far.